# command line list all files in directory & all combinations

Tags: macos, video, compare

I have a folder containing 7 mp4 videos.
I found a script that is able to combine two video's together in one video (split screen)

Now, I need to have a script that is able to return me all possibilities of video comparisons.

```
Example: my video directory (ex: only three files)
VID1.mp4
VID2.mp4
VID3.mp4
```

and what I need is a script that returns this:

```
VID1.mp4 VID2.mp4
VID1.mp4 VID3.mp4
VID2.mp4 VID1.mp4
VID2.mp4 VID3.mp4
VID3.mp4 VID1.mp4
VID3.mp4 VID2.mp4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algorithm: Iterate through all the .mp4 files (f1). Inside that loop, iterate through all the .mp4 files again (f2). If f1 != f2, then process the combination.

Assuming that your script to combine videos is called `combine-videos.sh`, here's a script to do what you are asking (I named it `combo-script.sh`):

```
#!/bin/sh

for f1 in `ls *.mp4`
do
  for f2 in `ls *.mp4`
  do
    if [ $f1 != $f2 ]
    then
      echo combine-videos.sh $f1 $f2
    fi
  done
done
```

Remove the `echo` when you are ready to actually run the script. Testing:

```
$ touch VID1.mp4 VID2.mp4 VID3.mp4
$ sh combo-script.sh
combine-videos.sh VID1.mp4 VID2.mp4
combine-videos.sh VID1.mp4 VID3.mp4
combine-videos.sh VID2.mp4 VID1.mp4
combine-videos.sh VID2.mp4 VID3.mp4
combine-videos.sh VID3.mp4 VID1.mp4
combine-videos.sh VID3.mp4 VID2.mp4
```

Note that this script assumes that the .mp4 files are in the same directory as the script.